# Upscaling videos with artificial intelligence?

Tags: windows-10, video, video-encoding

I am looking for a way to encode videos with AI upscaling (in Windows 10). I found [this article](https://captrobau.blogspot.com/2019/04/how-did-i-upscale-star-trek-ds9-footage.html) but it uses a method where you must split the video into individual frames (from command line), then upscale the pictures using AI gigapixel, then encode back to video. The problem I have with this method is that it involves so much manual labor it doesn't seem worth it. I tried Topaz Video Enhance AI but the problem with that is that it eats up all my 8gb GPU memory and still I am limited to 1080p upscaling. I cannot use the computer for entertainment while using this method because opening a video or a game causes a crash because my GPU memory is so tapped out.

I am looking for a reasonable method, like maybe one that can be accomplished completely in command line so it can be automated, or from a program that allows up to 4k work without me having to dedicate my computer for the work.

Comment: This is a *computationally hard* problem. DLSS is an AI-generated neural net for real-time upscaling in video games. The process involves a Nvidia DGX Supercomputer that they must run *each game* through to create a convoluter that can then be fed to the renderer. So you must be prepared for the process to take time, or you need to offload it to a secondary computer to allow the process to "bake." Offline rendering and batch processes to a group server in graphics and video processing are the norm.

Comment: No need for real time upscaling, I want to encode with upscaling, it can be as slow as needed, as long as it leaves resources for other things (low priority). The method I tested was 1 frame per second, which was great.